# Cannot run SQL script on Oracle Database 10g Express Edition

Tags: oracle10g, sql-scripts

I'm trying to upload a script, and the file is being uploaded fine, but in the Script Editor window where I'm going to actually run the script, the entire file content is shown on one line and the whole edit area is in red. I'm not being able to run that script. Also if I create a new script from the editor, the edit area is again in red and I'm not able to save it. Please help me understand what's to be done so that I can run my SQL scripts.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, so I figured it out by myself. So I'm answering my question so that it may help anyone else who have had this weird problem. When you open the database home page on any browser other than IE, this problem occurs, and you won't be able to do a single thing with your script. So always open your database home page on IE if you have to upload some data. For all other tasks, any other browser is fine. Cheers.